# Remove items from adapter/arraylist in for loop, preserving order of items

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter, simpleadapter

I am having a pretty difficult situation which I just can`t find a solution for.

I have a **sections** recyclerview which I fill with data through an arraylist, this data contains URL links and normal text.

The **normal text should be set as a section** in the recyclerview and the URLs as the items. The **tricky** part is that the arraylist needs to be in a specific **order** with the sections.

So the recylcerview should look like this **for example**:

```
URL
Section 1
URL
URL
Section 2
URL
URL
URL
URL
Section 3
etc...
```

I first tried to modify (remove) items from the arraylist itself but it won`t work as the sections and URLs are then out of order as they should be.

I then thought to load the whole list into the recylerview and before showing it **remove the relevant items** (marked as dummy in below code) from the SimpleAdapter but this doesn`t work in a for loop.

So how can I **remove** the dummy items from the **adapter or arraylist without losing the order** of the sections and URLs shown in the recylcerview?

In below code I fill the arraylist and set the sections.

```
public static List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
int k = 0;

for (String str : Arrays.asList(lines)) {
    str = unescapeJavaString(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(str)));

    if (!str.contains("some info")) {

     // if it is a URL add to arraylist, otherwise set section at relevant position in adapter.
     if (str.startsWith("http")) {
       test.add(k, str);
    } else {
      sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(k, str));
      test.add(k, "dummy"); // add dummy which should be removed.
    }
    k++;
  }
}
```

Removing it from the adapter, does not work either:

```
int i = 0;
  ...
mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, sCheeseStrings, userID, dlTypeValue);
  ...
recyclerView.setAdapter(mSectionedAdapter);

        Iterator itr = test.iterator();
            String strElement = "";
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                i++;
                strElement = (String) itr.next();
                if (strElement.equals("dummy")) {
                    mAdapter.remove(i);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
              }
         }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 2 list with separated URLS & dummies? Or just the adapter without dummies? Using 2 different views for the URLS and dummies in the adapter?

Comment: Hi Luca, it should just be 1 list but I set the dummies so I can remove them later. In other words if I remove the dummies the list is in order as it should be but I can not seems to get that. That`is why I also use a int "k" so that the items are set at the right place in the arraylist.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, you want to display `sect1, http, http, sect2, http, etc` but you want your list to only store http elements. You should do that inside the adapter class, after you displayed sect or http, you should remove sect from list inside the adapter

Comment: I also tried that in the onBindViewHolder method but I get an exception that recyclerview is still busy (setting up the list). I would need to remove from the adapter BEFORE the list is shown. Ìt is tricky indeed, this already keeps me busy 2 days now.

Comment: So why you need them in the list if you need to remove them BEFORE the list is shown? Just send to the adapter a copy of the list without the dummies item

Comment: If I knew how, I would already have done that. I tried several possible solutions already, none worked or I just cannot get it.
As sais the sections and URLs are provided throught the content in a certain order, which I need to maintain, that`s the difficult part.
I maintain that order by using the int "k", look at my method to fill the arraylist with URLs and the arraylist with the sections.
So when I remove the items marked as "dummy" I have what I need but the adapter already needs be set for that I guess.
If you have a better and easier way, I am all ears, as I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Try doing this:in the first place don't add anything to `sections`, use an adapter that accept a `ArrayList<String>`. In the `onBindViewHolder` BEFORE binding the correct layout, check whether the string is dummy or not, if it is, bind a `section` holder, if it's not bind a http holder instead. If you can't figure out how, let me know, I'll try to code a little bit

Comment: Ok Luca, thx I`ll give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131840/discussion-between-simon-and-luca-nicoletti).